# Matching a part with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How to read `@"TC__(\d{4}|\d{3})_8exp"`, if it is in the end of the Line!

**I am getting two results:**

```
TC__4373_8exp
TC__4373_8exp_source
```

**I want just:**

```
TC__4373_8exp
```

Code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"TC__(\d{4}|\d{3})_8exp");
var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.html").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien));
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But this is gonna match and this one TC__4373_8exp_source

Comment: Well, right now, `^TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$` or `(?m)^TC__\d{3,4}_8exp\r?$` or `(?m)TC__\d{3,4}_8exp\r?$` [should work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29TC__%5cd%7b3%2c4%7d_8exp%5cr%3f%24&i=TC__4373_8exp%0d%0aTC__4373_8exp_source). Could you please clarify where you get the matches from?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the idea is to read some paths and to get path that end with TC__4373_8exp but no the path that end with  TC__4373_8exp_source

Comment: `if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, @"TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$")) { /* VALID */ }`?

Comment: I have writen these Lines of code: Regex reg = new Regex(@"TC__(\d{4}|\d{3})_8exp"); var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.html").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien));

Comment: Please put the code into the question.

Comment: @kn1ghtxx especially for code, please add important info as [edit] to your question - much more visible and readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$` regex and you need to make sure the regex checks just the file name without extension:

```cs
var reg = new Regex(@"TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$"); 
var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.html")
    .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
    .Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien => 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien));
```

The `TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$` regex matches `TC__`, three or four digits, `_8exp` at the end of string.

The `.Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))` part will make sure your regex checks the file name without extension (i.e. without the `.html` part).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rOgZ9u/1).

You can simplify the code further to only call `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` once by selecting all file names with extension before running the regex check:

```cs
var reg = new Regex(@"TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$"); 
var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.html")
    .Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien => 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien))
    .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path));
```

Comment: When I use as a regex pattern this one: TC__\d{3,4}_8exp. I am getting values like  TC__4373_8exp, TC__4373_8exp_source. But when I use TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$ I am getting nothing!

Comment: @kn1ghtxx Right, you need to use `reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))`

Comment: Could you please write the hole code! Where do you mean to write this part!

Comment: @kn1ghtxx See the answer. Copy / paste it into your code.

Comment: If you remove the extension anway, move the select before the where to save the double remove.